# Multiply large numbers using multithreading

Tags: c, multithreading, operating-system

I need to multiply large numbers using multithreading. The two numbers to be multiplied can have up to 10000 digits. I have written multiplication code using a single thread. But I am not sure how to multiply when I am assigning multiple threads to different digits.

For example, if the two numbers are: 254678 and 378929 and there are 3 threads, I am assigning each of the two digits to one thread(2,5-Thread 1),(4,6->Thread 2),(7,8-> Thread 3) and each of the digits should multiply digits of 2nd number-> 378929.

When the threads will run in parallel I don't know how to manage the carry variable when multiple threads will update the variable at the same time.

input: array contains both the numbers
index: i1 contains the last digit of 1st number
index: i2 contains the last digit of 2nd number

```
enter code here
for (int i=i1-1; i>=1; i--){ 
    int carry = 0; 
    int n1 = input[i]; 
    t2 = 0;
    for(int j=i2-1; j>i1-1; j--){                                               
        int n2 = input[j]; 
        int sum = n1*n2 + output[t1+t2] + carry;
        carry = sum/10;
        output[t1+t2] = sum % 10; 
        t2++; 
    }
    if(carry > 0)                                                                   
        output[t1 + t2] += carry; 
    t1++; 
}
int main() { 
    pthread_t threads[MAX_THREAD];
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_THREAD; i++) 
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, &multiply, (void*)NULL); 

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_THREAD; i++) 
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL); 
}
```

Comment: Maybe you're going about this the wrong way.  Why not have each thread compute a whole line of multiplication for whatever digit you're interested in, and keep a partial sum.  When all threads are finished, add together all the partial sums.

Comment: I did think of doing this way but since the number of threads can be 100 and the output array size can be 10^8(10^4*10^4) the 2D array size will be 10^2 * 10^8=10^10.

Comment: No, if you have 100 threads, then you have only 100 accumulators / partial sums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When the threads will run in parallel I don't know how to manage the carry variable when multiple threads will update the variable at the same time.

Don't allow multiple threads to update anything at the same time.

Specifically (assuming each digit is a digit in "base 1<<32"), each thread can be like:

```
my_accumulator = table_of_per_thread_accumulators[thread_number];
for (int src1_digit_number = startDigit; src1_digit_number >= 0; src1_digit_number -= NUM_THREADS ) {
    for (int src2_digit_number = src2_digits-1; src2_digit_number >= 0; src2_digit_number-- ) {
        int dest_digit_number = src1_digit_number  + src2_digit_number;

        uint32_t n1 = input1[src1_digit_number];
        uint32_t n2 = input2[src2_digit_number];
        uint64_t r = (uint64_t)n1 * n2;
        while(r != 0) {
            uint64_t temp = my_accumulator[dest_digit_number] + (r & 0xFFFFFFFFUL);
            my_accumulator[dest_digit_number++] = temp;
            temp >>= 32;
            r = (r >> 32) + temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, when all threads are finished (after some "`pthread_join()`" calls?) you'd add the numbers from each thread's separate `my_accumulator` to get the actual result.

Note 1: In theory you can do some "binary merging of accumulators", such that an odd numbered thread waits for the next lower numbered thread to finish and adds that thread's accumulator to its own; then threads that satisfy "`my_thread_number % 4 == 3`" wait for the the thread numbered "my_thread_number - 2" to finish and adds its accumulator to its own; then... This is likely to be too complicated and messy to bother with.

Note 2: The alternative (if you use a single `output[]` that's modified by multiple threads) is to have a mutex to ensure only one thread can modify `output[]` at the same time (or multiple mutexes to ensure only one thread can modify a piece of `output[]` at a time); and this will destroy performance so badly that it will be faster to use a single thread.

Note 3: The alternative alternative is to use atomics somehow, or use inline assembly (e.g. "`lock add [output+rdi],eax;`") so that no mutex is needed. This is still very bad because the CPUs will be fighting for exclusive access of the same cache line (and you'll ruin performance by having CPUs spend most of their time trying to get exclusive access to the cache line).

Comment: Thank you so much. I got an idea of how should I proceed.